# EKEventstore and unique calendar identifier

Tags: ios, calendar, eventkit, ios5

I have a question about EKCalendar's `calendarIdentifier` property. Is this ID unique on a global level, or on a per-source level? E.g. can I safely store the calendarIdentifier in my app to smoothly identify a calendar across *all* calendars in the event store (no matter what EKSource they're in) or do I also need to save the EKSource's identifier associated with the calendar?

I have a calendar selection feature in my app, and I want to safely store and load the correct calendar (within the correct account) upon app restart.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience and from the description of the property in [EKCalendar's class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Reference/EKCalendarClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKCalendar/calendarIdentifier) it is local to the `EKEventStore`. An EKCalendar has an `EKSource` as it's property at the same level as the `calendarIdentifier` string.

Comment: I've found calendarIdentifier to be unique to the device, but not between devices.  I needed something to use across all devices via iCloud and this didn't work.  It seemed to be the same for some sources (Exchange and iCloud), but not for Gmail.  So, I'm stuck matching via stored name and source and asking the user when a match can't be found.

Comment: That's interesting, I would have assumed it to be unique to the iCloud account. One other thing you might want to check is the calendar colour as I think this is sync'd between devices. Hardly ideal, but might reduce the false negatives.

Comment: Can any one help in this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931231/how-to-identify-ekevent-uniquely-with-sync-across-the-devices